# cannot print XML with IE

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

After uploading files, feedback is displayed on the screen.

The JS code is as

```
$("#method_exec_file").click( function() {
    $('#param').upload('{/literal}{$smarty.server.SCRIPT_NAME}{literal}', function(XML_result) {
        $("#result_text").text( XML_result );
        $("#result_box").show("slow");
            },"");
 });
```

The XML result is as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <status>1</status>
  <data>
    <document_id>5ea17f928756ab64b46686d43c431cd756bac7f0</document_id>
    <external_service_file_key />
  </data>
</result>
```

it works with Chrome, FF, but cannot with IE7&10.  In Chrome, the XML result is a string, but in IE it's an object.

Much appreciation to any comments.

Comment: well.. the XmlHttpRequest object has methods that support XML and XSLT.. you are, however, using jquery.. so you'll probably benefit from a plugin.

Comment: Here is an interesting link from what of the jquery xslt plugin developers. http://www.jongma.org/webtools/jquery/xslt/xslt-test.html

Comment: I'm assigned to fix this...cannot get it done without plugins?

Comment: this is purely for display/print purposes? you aren't serving an xml file, just displaying the contents of it?

Comment: Yes, just for displaying. It comes in XML and I want to show it in XML, but this format will get lost when opened in IE, no problems at all with Chrome and FF

Comment: it seems because of IE's security setting, xml parsing with jquery is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to use $.parseXML()

Try:

var $xml =  $.parseXML(message) ;